# Determine LLVM versus GCC at compile time

Tags: gcc, xcode4, macros, llvm, conditional-compilation

I'm trying to write a macro similar to the following:

```
#ifndef DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE_MESSAGE
  #define DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE_MESSAGE(message) __attribute__((deprecated (message)))
#endif
```

And this works, but only with the Apple LLVM 3.0 compiler.  It breaks at compile time for anything else meaning I have to strip it down to

```
#ifndef DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE_MESSAGE
  #define DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE_MESSAGE(message) __attribute__((deprecated))
#endif
```

which is much less useful.

My question:

I think the solution is to apply some macro to identify the version of the compiler at compile time.  Is there a way to identify the Apple LLVM 3.0 compiler versus LLVM GCC 4.2 or GCC 4.2 (or anything else)?

Ideally, I'd like to work out something like this, but I can't find the right macro to figure it out:

```
#ifdef [Apple LLVM 3.0]
  #ifndef DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE_MESSAGE
    #define DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE_MESSAGE(message) __attribute__((deprecated (message)))
  #endif
#else
  #ifndef DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE_MESSAGE
    #define DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE_MESSAGE(message) __attribute__((deprecated))
  #endif
#endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work with [Clang’s feature checking macros](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html):

```
// In case the compiler/preprocessor doesn't support __has_extension
#ifndef __has_feature         // Optional of course.
  #define __has_feature(x) 0  // Compatibility with non-clang compilers.
#endif
#ifndef __has_extension
  #define __has_extension __has_feature // Compatibility with pre-3.0 compilers.
#endif    

#if __has_extension(attribute_deprecated_with_message)
  #ifndef DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE_MESSAGE
    #define DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE_MESSAGE(message) __attribute__((deprecated (message)))
  #endif
#else
  #ifndef DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE_MESSAGE
    #define DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE_MESSAGE(message) __attribute__((deprecated))
  #endif
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Apple LLVM compiler defines `__clang__`.

Comment: Clang defines `__clang__`, but `llvm-gcc` unfortunately does not. Does anybody know how to distinguish `gcc`from `llvm-gcc`? The reason I need this, is that `llvm-gcc` has some important differences. For example, `llvm-gcc` 4.2 does not define `__GXX_RTTI` when `gcc` does.

Comment: Here is the answer: `llvm-gcc` defines `__llvm__`.

Comment: The fact that `llvm-gcc-4.2` doesn't define `__GXX_RTTI` has nothing to do with the fact that it uses LLVM; that's just how gcc 4.2 behaves.

Comment: Are you saying that gcc 4.2 also does not define __GXX_RTTI? I assumed it did.

Comment: gcc 4.2 does not define __GXX_RTTI.